# How to extract the main diagonal of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know my question is very silly, but I cannot figure it out.

I have a $m \times m$ matrix $A$. I want to create vector $B$ such that its elements are the diagonal elements of matrix $A$. i.e. $i=j$, there for size of vector $B$ is gonna be $1 \times m$.

Can you help me how to right in math in a correct way? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Given $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$,

$$\mbox{diag}^{-1} (\mathrm A) := \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\mathrm e_i^{\top} \mathrm A \, \mathrm e_i\right) \mathrm e_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm e_i \mathrm e_i^{\top} \mathrm A \right) \mathrm e_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle \mathrm e_i \mathrm e_i^{\top}, \mathrm A \rangle \, \mathrm e_i$$

Comment: Why is $-1$ beside $diag$ ? More logical would be to use $v$ ( vector)..

Comment: @Widawensen Because $\mbox{diag}$ usually denotes the function that takes a vector and produces a diagonal matrix. I am using [Minka](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/matrix/minka-matrix.pdf)'s notation, as his cookbook was my first introduction to this topic.

Comment: Thank you for link to Minka. Interesting ..

Answer (score 1):

I would write:

Let the $ij^{th}$ element of $A$ be $a_{ij}$ and the $ij^{th}$ element of B be $b_{ij}$, then $b_{ij} = a_{mm}$ where $B=M_{1\times m}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have a matrix $A$ such that

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{22} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \ldots & a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Hence your vector $B$ would be

$$B = (b_1, b_2, b_3, \ldots, b_n) \equiv (a_{11}, a_{22} , a_{33}, \ldots ,  a_{nn})$$

Or also

$$B = \text{diag}\ (A)$$

The elements of $B$ will be the $a_{nn}$ elements of $A$, namely those for which $m = n$, that is the major diagonal elements.

So the $n-$th element of $B$ will be the term $a_{nn}$

For example the thord term of the vector $B$, that is $b_3$, will be $a_{33}$

Comment: Can you help me with this one as well please?

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992092/how-to-write-elements-of-a-matrix-to-a-vector-mathematically

Comment: Usually, $\mbox{diag}$ takes a vector and produces a diagonal matrix. What you're using is usually denoted $\mbox{diag} ^{-1}$, as it takes a matrix and produces a vector.