# How to write elements of a matrix to a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I know my question is very silly, but I cannot figure it out.

I have an $m \times m$ matrix $A$. I want to create a vector $B$ whose elements are the elements of matrix $A$ when $i+j \geq m-1$, i.e., all the elements of matrix $A$ that are either on the antidiagonal of it or underneath of its antidiagonal.

Meaning for

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\  7 & 8 & 9\end{bmatrix}$$

I want $B$ to be $B=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 5 & 7 & 6 & 8 & 9\end{bmatrix}$

Can you help me how to right in math in a correct way? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Is this for a programming work?

Comment: Yes, but I need mathematic notation

Comment: If you want $i + j \geq 3-1 = 2$, then the output should be the whole matrix!

Comment: Nah, 0=<i,j=<2, i+j>=3-1, would give you B.
A(0,0)=1,A(2,1)=7, ...

Answer (score 0):

at the time I cannot find a way for unifying them:

when $i=1,2,3$ then $b_i=a_{ij}, \; j=4-i,$

when $i=4,5$ then $b_i=a_{(i-2)j}, \;j=5-i,$

when $i=6$ then $b_i=a_{(i-3)j}, \;j=6-i$